# High dimensional volume entropy estimator

Tags: estimation, feature-selection, mutual-information

I am writing a program using high-dimensional volume (HDV) estimator to estimate entropy and mutual information for variable selection. Let $ D = (x^i_1, x^i_2, ..., x^i_M)$, N is the number of data points in the $M$ dimensional joint space.

The HDV estimators based on the equation as below:

\begin{aligned}
H(X) ≈ ψ(k) + ψ(N) + \frac{1}{N}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}{logB_m(r^{i}_{x^m})}^m}
\end{aligned}

$X$ is the random variable, $H(X)$ is the entropy of $X$, $ψ(.)$ is the digamma function,  $k=1$ for HDV estimator, $N$ is the number of observations, $B_m$ is the volume of m-dimensional unit ball $r^{i}_{x^m}$ is the minimum distance in each dimension:

\begin{aligned}
r^{i}_{x^m} = min(||x^i_m-x^{'i}_m||)
\end{aligned}

where $x^i_m \neq x^{'i}_m$ and $x^i_m , x^{'i}_m \in D$

My question is that when it is applied to estimate the entropy of Gaussian distribution with mean = 0 and standard deviation = 1, the theoretical result of entropy is around 1.4189. The program cannot get the result because $ψ(1)= 0.5772156$ (Euler-Mascheroni constant), $ψ(N=1000)= 6.9072$ (Say 1,000 of data points) and I think that $\frac{1}{N}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}{logB_m(r^{i}_{x^m})}^m}$ cannot be negative as it is about distance and volume. What is wrong of my understanding?

Comment: What is HDV? Could you provide a reference?

Answer (score 3):

The log term can be negative when minimum distance $||x^i_m - x'^i_m|| < 1$. This would happen if your samples are close to each other in one dimension. For a Gaussian distribution, most samples are within 1 standard deviation, so it should be negative.

Remember differential entropy can be negative, and in high dimension it is very sensitive to the most squashed direction of the distribution. For example, in your equation, $\log B_m(r^i_{x^m})$ can be negative infinity, if your data lives in a hyperplane (or rather, a hypercube).